# Count specific characters of json column in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Say I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
         id                                              geojson
0  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
1  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
2  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
3  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
4  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
5  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
6  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
7  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
8  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
9  1010020478  {"name": "entities"， "type": "FeatureCollectio...
```

I would like to count the number of `"type": "e"` or `"type":"e"` for each row

```
{
  "name": "entities"，"type": "FeatureCollection"，"features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature"，"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon"，"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              17.11460135135052，9.38631
            ]，[
              15.205521351350516，9.38631
            ]，[
              15.205521351350516，16.22718
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，16.22718
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，23.38623
            ]，[
              7.728291351350526，23.38623
            ]，[
              7.728291351350526，0
            ]，[
              17.11460135135052，0
            ]，[
              17.11460135135052，9.38631
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }，"properties": {
        "area": "104"，"name": "201"，"type": "e"，"Layer": "0"，"SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference"，"EntityHandle": "120A"
      }
    }，{
      "type": "Feature"，"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon"，"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              33.1826913513505，23.38623
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，23.38623
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，16.22718
            ]，[
              33.1826913513505，16.22718
            ]，[
              33.1826913513505，23.38623
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }，"properties": {
        "area": "125"，"name": "202"，"type": "e"，"Layer": "0"，"SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference"，"EntityHandle": "1223"
      }
    }，{
      "type": "Feature"，"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon"，"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              25.228191351350503，16.22718
            ]，[
              15.205521351350516，16.22718
            ]，[
              15.205521351350516，9.38631
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，9.38631
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，16.22718
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }，"properties": {
        "area": " "，"name": " "，"type": " "，"Layer": "0"，"SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference"，"EntityHandle": "1232"
      }
    }，{
      "type": "Feature"，"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon"，"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              33.1826913513505，16.22718
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，16.22718
            ]，[
              25.228191351350503，9.38631
            ]，[
              26.182731351350505，9.38631
            ]，[
              33.1826913513505，9.38631
            ]，[
              33.1826913513505，16.22718
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }，"properties": {
        "area": "22"，"name": " "，"type": "p"，"Layer": "0"，"SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference"，"EntityHandle": "123D"
      }
    }，{
      "type": "Feature"，"geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon"，"coordinates": [
          [
            [
              38.1144813513505，14.95446
            ]，[
              33.18269135135051，14.95446
            ]，[
              33.18269135135051，9.38631
            ]，[
              38.1144813513505，9.38631
            ]，[
              38.1144813513505，14.95446
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }，"properties": {
        "area": "20"，"name": " "，"type": "t"，"Layer": "0"，"SubClasses": "AcDbEntity:AcDbBlockReference"，"EntityHandle": "1267"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried with:

```
from collections import Counter

z = [""type": "e"", ""type":"e""]
df.geojson.str(Counter(z))
```

But I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. 
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you have like 3 different type of types LoL.... which one do you want to count???

Comment: Only `"type": "e"`, with or without space, please.

Comment: Okay, `type: e` is actually inside the `properties` inside the `type: feature, geometry`

Comment: Yes, I wonder why i can't treat this column as string and counter `"type": "e"` as specific characters?

Comment: Your `SyntaxError` comes from how you declared your `z`. You can't nest the same quotes like that, you either have to use single quotes outside or to protect your doubles quotes: `["\"type\": \"o\"", "\"type\":\"o\""]` or `['"type": "o"', '"type":"o"']`

Comment: I get another error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2878, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-fcc101cad0bd>", line 2, in <module>
    df.geojson.str(Counter(z))
TypeError: 'StringMethods' object is not callable`

Comment: Maybe something like this will work out:`len(df.geojson.['feature']["geometry"]['type']=="e")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def o_count(json_str):
    data = json.loads(json_str.replace("，", ","))
    try:
        result = []
        features = data['features']
        for x in features:
            result.append(x['properties']['type'])
        return result.count('o')
    except:
        return 0


df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
df["num"] = df.apply(lambda row: o_count(row['geojson']), axis=1)
```